# MS SQL loop through records and update column with aggregated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working with a Stored Procedure that has a piece of code as below:

```
UPDATE s 
SET EstimatedEffort = IsNull(s.EstimatedEffort, 0) + IsNull(sq.EstimatedEffort, 0),
EstimatedValue = IsNull(s.EstimatedValue, 0) + IsNull(sq.EstimatedValue, 0)
FROM #Story s
 JOIN (SELECT ji.ProjectID, 
              ji.ParentIssueID, 
              sum(ji.OriginalEstimate) 
                       * IsNull(pc.OverrideRate, c.DefaultRate) as EstimatedValue, 
              sum(ji.OriginalEstimate) as EstimatedEffort
         FROM JiraIssues ji
              LEFT JOIN ProjectComponents pc 
                   ON ji.ProjectID = pc.ProjectID
                      and ji.ComponentID = pc.ComponentID
              LEFT JOIN Components c 
                   ON ji.ComponentID = c.ComponentID
        WHERE ji.ProjectID = 12
          and ji.JiraIssueTypeID = 2
        GROUP BY ji.ProjectID, 
              ji.ParentIssueID, 
              pc.OverrideRate, 
              c.DefaultRate) sq
```

ON s.ProjectID = sq.ProjectID
      and s.IssueID = sq.ParentIssueID

Here, I have a temp table **#Story** which I'm trying to join with the results from Sub-query.

After doing this, I want to update values of two columns (EstimatedEffort and EstimatedValue) on the temp table such that all values for the same ProjectID should add up. I am able to populate both columns, however if there are multiple rows for the same ProjectID column in the sub query results, only the first gets added into the #Story table.

Is there a way using which I can add up all the values for a particular ProjectID from the sub query results, and store them in the #Story table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In subquery you grouping by 4 columns (ji.ProjectID, ji.ParentIssueID, pc.OverrideRate, c.DefaultRate). You should grouping only by 2 columns - ji.ProjectID, ji.ParentIssueID.

Comment: But I have to keep it in a Group By clause else it gives an error "Column 'ProjectComponents.OverrideRate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: try this
sum(ji.OriginalEstimate * IsNull(pc.OverrideRate, c.DefaultRate)) as EstimatedValue,